# Node mailer not sending email using c panel of godady

Tags: javascript, nodemailer, godaddy-api

Locally everything is fine and working perfectly.
When we have done the hosting the nodemailer is not working at all.
We used godady for hosing and using node js app on the goDady.

I have tried on locally that works good for node mailer on express app.
But when we host the node js app on go dady with cpanel then that is not working for nodemailer, others configurations are okay.
We are using node js version 10

Comment: What is exactly not working vai? May you share more code, details, screenshots and so on? A lot of companies also blocks sending outgoing mail for sure.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.